# Linkedin Sharing web page does not show summary

Tags: share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

We have been sharing our website pages and articles to LinkedIn for almost 4 years using

> https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://example.com/page1/

Until recently, the share block would appear with an image, caption and summary. Just as in Facebook. But now, we find that the summary does not show. I know many have raised this same concern here. One solution I saw in this forum is to switch to forcing visitors to sign into our LinkedIn app and post the status via REST API. My question is, Is this really necessary. We don't have a login feature for our website and to force people to login to LinkedIn app just to show description which is already part of the og tags on the page. Surely someone from LinkedIn can respond to this issue since so many have raised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Post Inspector (https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) to preview how your posts will be shared on LinkedIn.

Alternatively, you can use the Share Plugin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) to add a widget for users to easily share content on LinkedIn.

Comment: The inspector preview also does not show a description where as the same page displays a description in FB share.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a quick look at the **[Official LinkedIn "Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn" Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.  I will bold areas of particular interest:

> If you're the developer of your website, you'll need to **make sure the source code complies with Open Graph Protocol (OGP) and certain image requirements specific to LinkedIn**....
>
> Below are the og: tags that must exist and their correct format:
>
> ```
> <meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
> <meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
> <meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
> <meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
> ```

And the requirements...

> Here are the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing module:
>
> - Max file size: 5 MB
> - Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
> - Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

So, if you want to make sure your image displays correctly in the LinkedIn share functionality, make sure your webpage has the following...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="someweburl.jpg" />
</head>
...
</html>
```

*Hope this helps!*